# Disable the NavGrid buttons in JQGrid when grid is empty

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I want to Disable the NavGrid buttons in JQGrid when grid is empty.
I am using the following code, but buttons are not getting disabled.

```
    var rowCount = jQuery('#gridID').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
    if (rowCount == 0) {
       $("view_" + "#gridID").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
       $("refresh_" + "#gridID").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    }
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the above issue. See my below code:

```
  var rowCount = jQuery('#gridID').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
  if (rowCount == 0) {
       var grid = $("#gridID"),
       gid = $.jgrid.jqID(grid[0].id);

       var $viewBtn = $('#view_' + gid);
       $viewBtn.addClass("ui-state-disabled");

       var $refreshBtn = $('#refresh_' + gid);
       $refreshBtn.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
  }
```